# Where do I owe taxes while I am contracting overseas to Germany?

Tags: united-states, taxes, banking, germany, japan

I am currently a student in the US, but I am originally from Japan.

An IT company from Germany contacted me for a web application project and they told me they are going to send me the money to my Japan account.

But since the situation is a little complicated, I am not sure about Tax issue.

I will not pay any taxes in the US, since I am not working for a US company, and the company told me I have to pay taxes in Germany, but since they'll send me the money to my Japanese bank account, I am basically confused.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

> I will not pay any taxes in the Us, since I am not working for an US
>   company

What you will or will not pay is up to you of course, but you definitely **should** pay taxes in the US, as you're working in the US.

Since you mentioned being from Japan, I'll also suggest checking whether you're allowed to perform any work in the US under the conditions of your visa. If you're a F1/J1 student - you'll be breaking the immigration law and may be deported.

You might be liable for taxes in Germany, as well, and also in Japan.

---

I'll have to edit this to allow people who downvoted the answer without knowing the legal requirements to change their vote. F1 student **cannot** be a contractor without a valid EAD. Period. There's no doubt about it and legal requirements are pretty clear. Anyone who claims that you wouldn't be breaking the terms of your visa is **wrong**.

---

Note, I'm neither a lawyer nor a tax professional, for definite advice talk to a professional.

Comment: In principle, if you are an employee then you pay tax where you work. You work where your backside sits in an office chair - in this case, in the USA as described. You must be allowed to work where you work - in. this case, in the USA. In 2022, even if you sit in an office chair in the USA and your home computer in the USA is connected to a computer in an office in Germany, and the computer in Germany does all the real "work", you still work in the USA, even though everything really happens in Germany.